# Ableton and Wine... What happened?

Tags: wine

So I decided to install my copy of Ableton (v9.1) on my computer now that I've upgraded to a machine that isn't ancient.
HOWEVER
Despite WineHQ reporting that Ableton is platinum-certified, I can't get the dern thing to open.  It crashes out just as the splash screen pops up.  Sometimes I see it, sometimes not.  It tells me that some catastrophic error has occurred, and it needs to close.  I've tried this on two different systems running two different versions of wine 
(One runs the up-to-date public distro 1.6.2, while the machine I actually want to install it on is running the 1.7.19)

I don't know what to do.  I'd really just like to get this working, as my friends really like the look and feel of Ableton, and I really don't like LMMS (Linux-y free Audio Software).

Any idea what's going on here? I've found a couple of other people who seem to be having the same problem as me, but no dice on any solutions.  None provided, really.

Specs: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
 8 Gig ram 
i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz × 8 
Lots of free space... yadda yadda yadda

Error message: [link](http://textuploader.com/k0zk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's kind of in the nature of Wine where it'll sometimes out of the blue just slap you in the face and stop working. Especially with the development versions of Wine. There isn't a whole lot of things you can do about it other than to verify you did everything in the HOWTO section on WineHQ and to just try to run the same version of Wine where it was rated platinum.

[As you can see on Ableton's WineHQ page](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27440), it looks like it works best with Wine 1.5. In this case, a Wine front-end like [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) can help a lot because you can manage multiple versions of Wine with it in a very easy way. So that is another thing you can try!

Good luck and hopefully you can get it to work!

Comment: Hey!  That worked!  I don't know why I haven't tried POL before, but this is pretty slick!  thanks for your help!